# pip install django-adaptors overwriting 1.5 version of Django

Tags: django

When I install [django-adaptors](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) using  `pip install django-adaptors` it also seems to install django 1.4 in the process, which overwrites my django 1.5 installation.

How can I install django-adaptors without it overwriting my version of Django?

Thanks

Comment: I've raised a pull request against Django Adaptors (https://github.com/anthony-tresontani/django-adaptors/pull/8/files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install django-adaptors --no-deps`

Comment: Nice and clean, **but** this does **not** install the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply run `pip install django -U` after having installed `django-adaptors`. That will give you django-adaptors, *all its dependencies* and django 1.5. You could also simply download `django-adaptors` and change its dependencies file.

The advantage of this approach is that it is easily repeatable when you are moving to a production server (for instance in a *fabric* script).

One caveat, though: read the [django 1.5 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/) to know whether you are likely to encounter any problems.

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with the packages `setup.py`. You can see the source here: https://raw.github.com/anthony-tresontani/django-adaptors/master/setup.py

It defines `'Django==1.4'` rather than `'Django>=1.4'` so it will install Django 1.4 therefore overriding your 1.5 install.

All I can suggest is alter your `requirements.txt` so `django-adaptors` is above `Django==1.5` so when pip installs 1.5 would be installed after `django-adaptors` has installed 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

I just uploaded django-adaptors 0.2.4 which integrate Andrew Ingram fix that that.

You, then, just have to do again:

```
pip install django-adaptors
```